# Intrabars Candles Strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Im trying to calculate Lower candles inside a bigger one for running mine strategy but seem something is wrong.

Explaining how it works:

- Setting a main Timeframe (Daily for example  -> this is the timeframe for Main Bar)
- Setting a second Timeframe (1 Hour for example)
- Setting Profit Target %  (5% for example)
- Setting Stop Target %   (2% for example)

Conditions:

- When `live_price` is major then `open` of the Main Bar: open long trade
- If `live_price` touch `Profit_Target`: close the trade
- If `live_price` touch `Stop_Target`: close the trade
- In case neither of the two options occurs: close the trade at the closing of Main Bar

Here a visual example where: Main Timeframe is Daily and the Second Timeframe is 1 hour.

[image]

I post the code i do, well commented here:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=5
strategy("OHLC Strategy", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true) //calc_on_every_tick -> necessary for 'live_price'

// Inputs
// -------
main_timeframe   = input.timeframe(title='Main Timeframe',   defval='D')
second_timeframe = input.timeframe(title='Second Timeframe', defval='60')
stop_target      = input.float(title='Stop Target %',        defval=1, step=0.01, tooltip='Negative')
profit_target    = input.float(title='Profit Target %',      defval=1, step=0.01, tooltip='Positive')

// Save Open-High-Close values into Variables
//-------------------------------------------
timeframe_main_open  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, main_timeframe, open,  gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)  
timeframe_main_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, main_timeframe, close, gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)
live_price           = close

// Calculate Targets
//------------------
stop_value   = ((-stop_target  * timeframe_main_open) / 100) + timeframe_main_open  // Stop Percentage using open Major Bar  
profit_value = ((profit_target * timeframe_main_open) / 100) + timeframe_main_open  // Profit Percentage using open Major Bar

// C O N D I T I O N S 
//======================
bool find_long = live_price <= stop_value ? true : false   // Check condition at every new Main Bar

if find_long
   if live_price >= timeframe_main_open
        strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)

strategy.exit('Long | Exit | Stop Target', stop=stop_value)        // Close trade when live_price touch stop target
strategy.close('Long | Close | Profit Target', stop=profit_value)  // Close trade when live_price touch profit target
 
// Close when Main Bar is closed | Not sure it works
if barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.close_all(comment='Long | Close | Expired time')
```

Well, i tried this code but seems something doesn't works, any help on the kind of approach to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

timeframe_main_open has value only during one candle. You need to store that value to be able to calculate stop_value and profit_value on all periods

```
openBuff             = ta.valuewhen(timeframe_main_open, open, 0)
// Calculate Targets
//------------------
stop_value   = ((-stop_target  * openBuff) / 100) + openBuff  // Stop Percentage using open Major Bar  
profit_value = ((profit_target * openBuff) / 100) + openBuff  // Profit Percentage using open Major Bar
```

2. 

*find_long* does not make sense.

Try this:

```
find_long = ta.crossover(live_price, openBuff)
if find_long
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)
```

3. 

And for debug, plot all the lines

```
plot (
  openBuff,
  title      = "openBuff",
  color      = color.gray)
plot (
  stop_value,
  title      = "stop_value",
  color      = color.red)
plot (
  profit_value,
  title      = "profit_value",
  color      = color.green)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gu5tavo71, it was very helpfull your reply. I didn't cosiderate use `ta.valuewhen()`. Last question: do you know how can i close all the trade opened when the major candle is closed? for Example: if the major timeframe is daily, and the second one is hourly, all trade 'll be close when major bar is closed? Probably i should use something like `isbarlast`?. Anyway thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Open a new question, with this